# The results of the path setting are different

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path, operating-system, rename

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IIAf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNTuE.png)

I want to bring files from a specific folder. but even if the folder is routed, the result will be the same when executed. Help me.

To rename files collectively
I want to route the folder and put the files in the folder on the list.

```
**coding:** 
file_path = 'C:/Users/X1 Carbon/Desktop/기타'
    file_names = os.listdir(file_path)
    file_names


**result:** 
PS C:\Users\X1 Carbon\Desktop> & "C:/Users/X1 Carbon/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe" "c:/Users/X1 Carbon/Desktop/why.py"
```

Comment: Could you put you entire code? As your description, the code work correctly, list the file of the `file_path`.

Comment: The subfile in that folder is something else. it is not 'C:/Users/X1 Carbon/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe'

Comment: The `C:/Users/X1 Carbon/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe` is not any "subfile" like you say, it's python interpreter - your Visual Studio Code has to run the file, right? So it has to use python (this path) + your .py file path

Comment: I want to get a list of files under the 'C:/Users/X1 Carbon/Desktop/ooter' folder. For example, the names of the files are 'a', 'b', 'c'. but executing the code results in a 'PS C:\Users\X1 Carbon\Desktop> & "C:/Users/X1 Carbon/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe" ,"c:/Users/X1 Carbon/Desktop/why.py"'.  The result is unknown addresses. It's not even a file name, it seems like an address.

Comment: why not use `print(file_names)`? what do you mean by "route"?

Comment: Oh, I'm a fool. Thank you so much :( Thank you for answering such a stupid answer..

Answer (score 0):

```
PS C:\Users\X1 Carbon\Desktop> & "C:/Users/X1 Carbon/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe" "c:/Users/X1 Carbon/Desktop/why.py"
```

This execution path consists of three parts：

```
PS C:\Users\X1 Carbon\Desktop>
```

This section is the current path in the terminal.

```
"C:/Users/X1 Carbon/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe"
```

This section is your Python interpreter, and the shell needs to find your `python.exe` to start Python.

```
"c:/Users/X1 Carbon/Desktop/why.py"
```

This section is the python file which you run.

Returning to the problem itself, there were no errors in your code. If you hover your mouse over the `file_names`, you'll find that the type of it is **list**.

[image]

You're right, happy coding.